# Xcode: how to access shared photo albums in MacOS 10.10

Tags: macos, shared, photos

I'm using the Media library for identifier: "com.apple.Photos.SharedGroup" and I'm able to parse thru all my shared photo albums by adding observers using the observeValueForKeyPath method to extract MLMediaObjects to get URL's of the shared photo albums.

I get paths (derived from URL) like this:

/Users/myusername/Library/Containers/com.apple.cloudphotosd/Data/Library/Application Support/com.apple.cloudphotosd/services/com.apple.photo.icloud.sharedstreams/assets/C040C174-A26E-490B-92EF-22C261F0A531/8F5060DE-F718-4F6C-A978-439E8F28DEB2/IMG_0009.JPG

When I paste this path into Finder I can access the JPG file correctly.

However Xcode gives me this runtime warning when I try to do an NSData read from the URL:  "The file “IMG_0009.JPG” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it."

Presumably, these containers are hidden from Apps? If so, how else can I access these photo images.

I'm developing cross platform (IOS, MacOS) apps to access the same set of shared photo album images on both platforms. I have no problem doing this in IOS using the PhotoKit.